# Permission to use mobile data on android application

Tags: android, permissions, android-data-usage, mobile-data

i have made an update to my app present in playstore. my problem is that after publishing the update, on some phones(like mine "xiaomi Poco F1") when i installed the app, data usage restriction was turned on to wifi only.
So how to add permission to use mobile data.

Those are permissions on my app

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: Xiaomi devices (devices on MIUI OS) have settings to put on restrictions on type of data being used by any app. Unfortunately, you can't add permission that overrides this - the user has to do it manually in app settings

Comment: But on the old version of my app, it was not putting any restriction. is it because i upgraded to sdk (API 29)?

Comment: It might not be just because of update to your app, MIUI12 came out this July & August, so it might be connected to updated OS security